# Error detected while processing function <SNR>110_RestartServer[1]..<SNR>110_SetUpOptions[10]..<SNR>110_SetUpSigns:line28: E730:using List as a String

Tags: neovim, youcompleteme

I just installed the YouCompleteMe plugin using vim-plug on nvim
when i open nvim i get this error:

`Error detected while processing function <SNR>110_RestartServer[1]..<SNR>110_SetUpOptions[10]..<SNR>110_SetUpSigns: line   28: E730: using List as a String`

When i restart the server, this is the error i get:

```
Restarting ycmd server... The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ':YcmRestartServer'). Unexpected exit code 1. Type ':YcmToggleLogsycmd_47051_stderr_8bgeimju.log' to check the logs.
```